# Stylus.set() not updating the output.

Tags: javascript, css, stylus

I am want to access javascript values in my stylus, which i am doing like this below. This function outputs the values perfectly, but its not updating my test.css file.

```
var config = {
    sizes:{
        width:"500px",
    height:"200px"
    },
  background:"rgba(10,10,100)",
  color:[100,10,10,.5],
    someArray:[100,0,0,2]
};

var str = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname+'/test.styl',{encoding:'utf8'});

var stylus = require('stylus');

var stylusVars = require('stylus-vars')(config,{delimiter:'-'});
// the delimiter option defines how nested objects will be represented

stylus(str)
    .set('filename','test.css')
    .use(stylusVars)
    .render(function(err, css){
        if(err){throw err;}
        console.log(css);
});
```

What does the stylus.set() do ?

Comment: Shouldn't you write the file? `fs.writeFile('test.css', css)`

Answer (score 0):

You should write the result css to a file with `fs.writeFileSync('test.css', css);` instead of outputting it through `console.log`. `.set` is just a method to set stylus options (`filename` in your case, this option is needed to resolve relative paths inside `@import`statements).